# Top 5 rows by month

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a set of Google Anlaytics data in a spreadsheet that lists all the pages viewed over a period of time by month. So it looks like;

```
Month | Page Title | Page Views | Visitors | Bounce Rate  
Dec       Page1         250         199          20  
Dec       Page2         240         189          10  
Nov       Page1         260         192          30  
Nov       Page2         250         190          10
```

On a Summary page I have a drop down to select the month for which I want data, there are several bits of data that work of this.

For this particular set of data "Top 5 Popular Pages by Month" I want to select the Month and then return the top 5 pages for that month.

I realise this can be done with a pivot table that has month as filter and a bit of VBA but I so far i have avoided VBA for this spreadsheet and would like to find a way to do it without code, I am happy to use intermediate/helper columns/tables it doesn't have to be a megaformula.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is turn on the Filter, select a single month, sort largest to smallest by either page views or visitors, and then delete all but the top six rows (header plus top 5). You could probably do this fairly easily with a Record Macro, with the added caveat that the single month you select would come from your Summary page dropdown. To change that in the VBA code, you would look for a line that looks something like this: Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Printer" and then change the arguments to fit your needs.

Comment: @user2800 I am trying to do it without code.

Comment: @Naz, this can be done by using Sort on Month and Pivot Table,, using Month as prime field, then use Print Layout option, Check Insert page break after each Date,, and while print Set, Page to Print From 1 to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops I left out the final grab of the page name and didn't metion it's an array function!  Thank you HackSlash.

```
{=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("dec"&LARGE(IF(A:A="dec",C:C),1),A:A&C:C,0),1)}
```

THIS IS AN ARRAY FUNCTION.  You must press cntrl shift enter to make Excel put the brackets around the outside of it to work.

This returns the value of column B where the value of column C is greatest where column A contains "dec".  Change the 1 to 2 for second, to 3 for third, etc...

You can use a cell reference instead of "dec" if you want.

Comment: I can't see how this would return the page title

Comment: Yeah, you would need to add an INDEX\MATCH to pull a different column from the located row.

Comment: The Match gets a bet complicated when there are equal results. `LARGE({5,10,5,1},x)` x=2 and x=3 both return 5. Also in the answer, change `,1` to `,ROW($A1)` and the copy down will increment $A1 -> $A2 -> $A3 ... and the ROW function on this value automatically provide 1, 2, 3 ... No need to make changes on every row.

Comment: @TedD. yes, using a reference like row() or row()-1 or row($A1) is a good choice.  I think I solved the multiple match results with the combining of fields with "&" in the match function.

Comment: @Naz *fixed the result

Comment: @Brian, I think you will find if there are two pages with the same number of views in dec, say 500, then concatenating "dec" & 500 will not uniquely identify one from the other and MATCH will return the first page title of dec with 500 views both times LARGE returns 500.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following into the formula bar for the first result cell (top result). *Pasting directly to the cell may split this formula across several cells due to the line break formatting*:

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( $R$4:$R$13, MATCH(
   MAX( IF( $Q$4:$Q$13=$R$14, IF( NOT( COUNTIF( $Q$14:$Q14, $R$4:$R$13)), $S$4:$S$13, ""), "")),
   IF(  $Q$4:$Q$13=$R$14, IF( NOT( COUNTIF( $Q$14:$Q14, $R$4:$R$13)), $S$4:$S$13, ""), ""),
   0)), "")
```

Modify:

- $Q$4:$Q$13 = Month Data Column
- $R$14 = Pick List Cell of Month to display
- $R$4:$R$13 = Page Title Data Column (The titles for a given month
  must be **unique**, see below)
- $Q$14:$Q14 = Cell above Top Result Formula (the cell referenced
  must not contain a possible page title)
- $S$4:$S$13 = Comparison Number (page views or visitors) either
  from a Data Column or a calculated result (intermediate/helper) column
- All references are absolute except the second cell's row number in the
  "results so far" range $Q$14:$Q**14**
- The following ranges must be the same size:

  - Month Data Column *$Q$4:$Q$13*
  - Page Title Data Column *$R$4:$R$13*
  - Comparison Number (page views) Data Column *$S$4:$S$13*

Once edited enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> since this is a CSE formula.
Then drag down however many top result rows are needed. (This could be set programmatically from another picklist.)

**Unique values:** If two Page Titles (say the "Home" page from two different sites) may be the same for the given month, then a helper column will be needed.

- The helper column will contain the above formula with some extra columns
  concatenated, say <url>&<title>, to uniquely identify rows within
  a given month (more than two column concatenations is also fine).
- Everywhere the formula uses Page Title `$R$4:$R$13`, substitute the concatenation
  `$U$4:$U$13 & $R$4:$R$13`, where $U$4:$U$13 is the url data column.
- Even the first argument of INDEX is substituted which will generate a
  concatenated helper column of results.
- The value of $Q$14:$Q14 is now a reference to the cell above the helper column's
  top result cell (above the cell with this formula). The cell referenced (above
  the helper columns result list) must not contain any values which could possible
  be values found in this helper column concatenation results.
- The displayed results formula will then be
  `=IFERROR( INDEX( $R$4:$R$13, MATCH( $H15, $U$4:$U$13 & $R$4:$R$13, 0)), "")`
  where $H15 is the first (top) result cell in the helper column.
- This new formula is CSE because of the array concatenation.
- Copy drag down to increment the relative row reference $H15 (the helper column's
  first cell) so the row reference increments to reference the following rows.
- Tested.

**How It Works**

- The IFERROR is a simple guard for when all the data for a given month has already been ranked and displayed in the results.
- The `INDEX($R$4:$R$13,` is used to get the matching value result from the Page Title data column.
- MATCH and MAX use the same list of values. Match finds the index in this list where the MAX of the list is located.
- A series of nested IFs resulting in an array of values. The resultant array contains the comparison values to be considered by MAX and searched in by MATCH.
- The first filter `$Q$4:$Q$13=$R$14` compares each element of the Month data column (array) to the pick list value. The result is an array of true/false based on whether the row of the month data column matches the pick list value. For each True element the IF returns the nested IF result and "" otherwise.
- Nested IFs work at the same index of the array as the outer IFs. All the arrays must be the same size. If({True,False},{"a","b"},If({True,True},{1,2}) ) is IF({True,False},{"a","b"},{1,2}). Row 1 is If(True,"a",1), row 2 is If(False,"b",2) resulting in {"a",2}.
- The second filter `NOT(COUNTIF( $Q$14:$Q14, $R$4:$R$13))` also returns a true/false array. The array element is true if the row of the page title data column (second argument to COUNTIF) is not in the previous top results `$Q$14:$Q14`.

  - The previous top results array grows as the formula is copied/drug down because the second cell reference of the range is relative. For each subsequent result, there will be more page titles filtered out with false.
  - The second filter's true/false array has one element for each row of the Page Title data column.
  - The COUNTIF function is used on each page title in the page title data column. The COUNTIF function counts all the times this particular Page Title (from the Page Title column data array) is found in the previous results `$Q$14:$Q<grows>`. If there are zero finds, the count is zero (the expect result is zero or one).
  - The results of COUNTIF are given to NOT. A boolean test on a number returns false for zero and true otherwise. The negation of the NOT function makes this result true if zero (not found in previous results) and false otherwise (found COUNT times in previous results).
  - For each row of the array that has a True value, IF returns the same row of the comparison value array and "" otherwise.
- This effectively replaces unwanted values with a "" while preserving the values to consider.
- MAX returns zero if all the values are "", otherwise the largest number is returned even if it is negative.
- MATCH will not match zero against an empty string even though there are places Excel treats an empty string as zero (this is not one of those times). This is the guard against erroneous results when there are page(s) with zero visits.
- The last zero is the third argument to MATCH so it will consider exact matches only (and is also needed on an unsorted/unordered list, which this is).